# Is there another way besides Android Facebook API to access profile photos of your friends

Tags: android, facebook, profile, photos

I want to automatically (not by manually selecting through the internal facebook app) download profile photos of my friends from Android. I am guessing there is no other way than to use Facebook API?

Do I really need to register the app on facebook? I would like to avoid that if possible..

Thank you. Cheers, Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is, No you should use the Graph API for it.

Long answer, you could let a user sign in to facebook and than search the HTML for the profile pictures.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i was afraid of.. Searching manually is not an option, since it needs to be automated to find a list of friends photos. Do you know if i could maybe use an Intent to get pics by calling the internal facebook app?.. Thank you very much for your reply. Best regards, Val

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying...

The best way to do it is to do client side authentication and then use the Graph API. Then query for the friends with https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends and then get for every user id the profile picture by using graph.facebook.com/{userId}/picture

Comment: I think you mean "consent with "intent"?

Comment: Yes in the form of: `Intent get_photo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); get_photo.setType("image/jpeg"); then getExtra(..);` Android would offer to open the apps capable of using this intent.

Comment: oke, Sorry that was my insufficient knowledge of android -_-'. If you've never worked before with the FB API there is some good documentation over here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/

Comment: I'm new to android too. :) Thank you for your help. Cheers Val